# How show that the Dantzig selector is equal to the Lasso when we are in the orthonormal case

Tags: lasso, convex

I think all is in the title but I just will recall what is the Lasso and the Dantzig selector

Lasso:We want minimize $\frac{1}{n}||y-X\theta||^2+2\tau|\theta|_1$

Dantzig: we want to minimize $|\theta|_{1}$ with the condition $|\frac{1}{n}X^{T}(y-X\theta)|_{\infty}\leq \tau$

(where y is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$,X a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ and $\tau$ is a number and $|| \ . ||$ denote the euclidian norm )

What I call "orthonormal case" is simply the fact that:
$X^TX=\frac{1}{n}I_p $

I’d like to add that I have very few knowledge about the lasso and convexity problem in general, so if you could explain me without use some complex explanations that seems trivial for you it's would be great!

Thank you a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure how to construct this proof from scratch, but I think this resource has everything you need: http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/Research/JRSSB_copy.pdf -- is there a specific part of the proof that you have trouble with? To be fair, I do think that this is a little hard to show from scratch without some basic knowledge of convex optimization.

Comment: Ok thank you! I already see this paper but they demonstrate something more general: they just need that $X^TX$ has full rank, maybe with my assumption which is stronger, there is a more simple way to prove the results? What is difficult for me is that in the lasso it's the euclidian norm that is involved but in the Dantzig, it's the infinite norm, and i don't see how to go from this norm to the other. I saw in one paper the dual of the Lasso problem, and it was use infinite norm, but I'm not sure that it is simple to find the dual of the Lasso problem...